# Adding a Navigation Drawer to an existing ConstraintLayout Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Is there any way that I can modify the XML file of my main activity (the one that I wish to add a navigation drawer to) so as to allow for my existing layout to remain while adding the navigation drawer?

My current code is as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:src="@drawable/monetwaterloo" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendPhoto"
    android:text="@string/button_photo_send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="checkDatabase"
    android:text="@string/check_database_items"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />
```

And this results in the following:

[image]

So essentially, all I just want a drawer navigation to appear beside the title... Any help or guiding advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The DrawerLayout needs to be the top view, and the ConstraintLayout would be in it with a gravity of `start`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap the whole thing in a drawer layout and then add a second view which will act as the drawer layout. See below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="204dp"
            android:layout_height="139dp"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:src="@drawable/monetwaterloo" />

    </LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendPhoto"
    android:text="@string/button_photo_send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="checkDatabase"
    android:text="@string/check_database_items"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately now I am getting two action bars at the top? Is this as a result of there being two activities? I'm really new to Android development and am just experimenting, hence the confusion. Any help will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by two activites, but in my setup I used a NoActionBar theme and had my own toolbar which I set as the supportActionBar so that is how that worked.